# Cookie value changes back to previous value after changing

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development, functions, cookies

I have this custom pligin that im using in order to save the user's language preferences. I store it as a cookie like so:

```
<?php
    
    add_filter( 'init', 'aws_set_language_cookie', 999 );
    function aws_set_language_cookie() {
        global $TRP_LANGUAGE;
        if ( isset( $TRP_LANGUAGE ) ) {
            $result = setcookie( 'language', $TRP_LANGUAGE, time() + ( 30 * DAY_IN_SECONDS ), "/", "" , true, true );
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Now if you take a look at the website https://ugrandchurch.com/ open cookies in inspect element after switching to Spanish. You will see that a cookie by the name of "language" created which holds the value of "es_ES" is saved but it changes to "en_EN" after 3 seconds.

How can I make sure that the value of Spanish "es_ES" is kept instead of being taken overriten by "en_EN".

The WordPress language plugin used here is by the name of TranslatePress

Comment: In my browser "es_ES" doesn't change to "en_EN" after 3 seconds. Why do you need to set cookie by yourself. I guess TranslatePress plugin should store users language somewhere in session

Comment: @anton thats my bad im sleep deprived i posted the question and started working on different solutions i was changing the cookie files now its the original you can see what i mean

Comment: Guess problem is in other function. this filter doesn't fire on your language select change.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see this happening on your site, but I think you could probably remove the variable declaration in front of setcookie(). I didn't see result called used any where in this code. Which makes me wonder if the value is being set because since the variable isn't used.

```
<?php
    
    add_filter( 'init', 'aws_set_language_cookie', 999 );
    function aws_set_language_cookie() {
        global $TRP_LANGUAGE;
        if ( isset( $TRP_LANGUAGE ) ) {
            setcookie( 'language', $TRP_LANGUAGE, time() + ( 30 * DAY_IN_SECONDS ), "/", "" , true, true );
        }
    }
    ?>
```

I hope this helps, sorry if it doesn't :)